# Best way to refresh data from server after adding new Data using retrofit2

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, retrofit2

In my case scenario as I use Compose, I add data to the server and read them from it, but after adding the new data and storing it in MutableListState when I go back to the main screen where the list of data is represented, the new data isn't shown as the API call was already done and If I close the app and reopen the new data read normally, so I want the best way to refresh the data from the server after adding. I am thinking about recalling the API again on my screen by using a launchedEffect, but I believe there are better ways than this. something like Firebase real-time database feature.

```
My Code for example is like this:

   

     Class HomeRepository @Inject constructor(
        val service : ApiServieces
    ) : IHomeRepository {
    
        override suspend fun getHomeData() = service.getHomeData()
    
        override suspend fun getProfileData() = service.getProfileData()
.................
```

Then I use it in my UseCase

```
class CheckPhoneUseCase @Inject constructor(private val repository: IRegistrationRepository) {

fun checkPhone(phoneBodyModel: PhoneBodyModel) : Flow<Resource<BaseResponse>> = flow{
    emit(Resource.Loading())
    try {
        val response = repository.checkPhoneNumber(phoneBodyModel).toDomain()
        emit(Resource.Success(response))
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        emit(Resource.Error(e.message ?: "Error Occurred!"))
    } catch (e : HttpException) {
        if (e.code() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_NOT_FOUND) {
            emit(Resource.Error("Phone Number Not Found!"))
        } else {
            emit(Resource.Error("Error Occurred!"))
        }
    } catch (e : IOException){
        emit(Resource.Error("Failed to connect to server! check you internet connection!"))


      }
   }
   }
```

and Use it in the ViewModel and Call the API method in the Composable function

```
    private fun getCampaigns() {
    getCampaignsUseCase().onEach{ response ->
        when(response){
            is Resource.Loading -> {
                _isLoadingProgressBar.emit(true)
            }
            is Resource.Success -> {
                _state.value = ResponseState(isSuccess = response.data?.status ?: false)
                _campaignsData.value = ResponseCampaigns(isSuccess = response.data?.data)
                Log.v("TAG", "getCampaigns: ${_campaignsData.value.isSuccess?.current?.items?.data?.size}")

                for (item in response.data?.data?.current?.items?.data!!){
                    _campaignListCurrent.add(item)
                }
                _campaignListCurrent.removeAt(0)
                for (item in response.data.data.completed.items.data!!){
                    _campaignListCompleted.add(item)
                }
                _campaignListCompleted.removeAt(0)
                _isLoadingProgressBar.emit(false)
                Log.v("TAG", "_campaignListCompleted: ${_campaignListCompleted}")

            }
            is Resource.Error -> {
                _isLoadingProgressBar.emit(false)
                Log.v("TAG", "_campaignListCompletedErorr: ${_campaignsData.value.isError}")
                Log.v("TAG", "_campaignListCompletedErorrMessage: ${response.message}")


            }
        }
    }.launchIn(viewModelScope)
}
```

This way I get the data, bat cant refresh it when I add new data from the server unless I close the app and recall the Api method again.

Comment: Show us the code that produces that behavior, and the code that reads data from the Realtime Database.

Comment: I updated my question, I want the best way and practice to refresh data from the server when I add new data, I can recall the API methods again everytime i add new data, but I believe this is expensive especially in compose as the recomposition will be triggered for the hall view, So i am asking for the best solution here.

Comment: I'm not sure how is this question related to Retrofit2? Besides that, your `checkPhone` function returns a flow, then how do you collect the data? I also cannot see how you query the Realtime Database. I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-make-a-clean-architecture-android-app-using-mvvm-firestore-and-jetpack-compose-abdb5e02a2d8) will help. If for Firestore, but the same rules apply in the case of the Realtime Database. Here is the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/FirestoreCleanArchitectureApp).